# Access routeProvider's route properties

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

For a route defined like this:

```
$routeProvider
.when('/',
{
    templateUrl:'views/login.html',
    controller:'Login',
    private:false
});
```

How can I access the `private` property inside a `$routeChangeStart` event for example?
Currently I'm using `current.$$route.private` to get it, but it seems wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is actually [recommended](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#attach-custom-data-to-state-objects) to put all your custom data with routes inside a "data" object as such.

```
$routeProvider
.when('/',
{
    templateUrl:'views/login.html',
    controller:'Login',
    data: {
       private: false
    }
});
```

Here is how I access route params

```
$rootScope.$on( "$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
   next.data.private;
});
```

The second parameter of the routeChangeStart event is the route object that is called. Another advantage is that anything in the `data` object is passed to children states.

Comment: Thanks. It works with `next.hideHeader`. It's odd because I console.log`ed `next` and it only showed as being a property on `$$route`.

Comment: Sorry Nicolas, I downvoted and commented it didn't work then realized I was examining the next property in OnLocationChangeStart not routeChangeStart.  Now I can't upvote it again apparently because it's been more than an hour, again, sorry.

Comment: MY INTERNET POINTS!!!!! Gimme back NAOW. JK I'm glad to see people are still using/proofreading my answers.

Comment: can you cite where this is recommended with a link?

Comment: your link refer to the ui-router doc, not the native ngRoute. Do you have a link to the ngRoute documentation ? Can't find one. Tx

Answer (score 1):

`$routeChangeStart` happens prior to the route changing, so you need to look at `next`.  There's no need to use `next.$$route` since next [inherits from](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngRoute/route.js#L563-L565) `$$route`.

```
angular.module('example', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/',  {
      controller: 'MyCtrl',
      template:   '<b>isPrivate: {{isPrivate}}</b>',

      private: false
    });
  })

  .run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
      /* 
       * this is fired prior to the route changing, so your params will be on
       * next.  Here we just attach it $rootScope as an example.
       * note that you don't need to use next.$$route since $$route is private,
       * and next inherits from next.$$route. */
       */
      $rootScope.isPrivate = next['private'];
    });
  })
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

  })
```

Comment: Yeah, OK, `next`, but the point was, is it OK to use `$$route`? It looks to me as if it was made to be used internally by Angular, less so by implementors.

Comment: [The Docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05) say that `If you inspect a Scope, you may also notice some properties that begin with $$. These properties are considered private, and should not be accessed or modified.`  So it seems not.

Comment: Oddly enough, it just works without the `$$route`. Thanks though.

Comment: If you look at the [source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngRoute/route.js#L563-L565) it looks like `next` inherits from `$$route` (set a breakpoint and check `next.__proto__`), so all the route properties should be on `next`.  Good find.

Comment: Yup. However, NicolasMoise from above found this out.